# I want to split a SQL query by column wise with comma separator. But some datatype having comma inside it. Need to exclude those comma

Tags: java, regex

For below query I want split with comma by ignoring comma inside the brackets eg  DECIMAL(20,4)
Please suggest some regex which will help to split the string

```
data1   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,
data2   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,
data3   DECIMAL(16) NOT NULL,
data4   VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
data5   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,
data6   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,
data7   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,
data8   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,
data9   DECIMAL(20,4) ,
data10  DECIMAL(20,4) ,
data11  DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,
data12  DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
,(?![^(]*\\))
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/8T6Ckt/1

Answer (score 0):

The RegEx to find the "," just before end of line is (,$)
i.e for

```
data1   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,
data2   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,
data3   DECIMAL(16) NOT NULL,
data4   VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
data5   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,
data6   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,
data7   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,
data8   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,
data9   DECIMAL(20,4) ,
data10  DECIMAL(20,4) ,
data11  DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,
data12  DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,
```

and in case its in minified format like:

```
data1 DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,data2 DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,DECIMAL(20,4),
```

you can use "`[^0-9,],`"

It will find all the "," at the end of line. you can test the same in https://regex101.com/

Comment: But the query may be in one line also, Like


 data1   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,data2   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,data3   DECIMAL(16) NOT NULL,    data4   VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,    data5   DECIMAL(20,4) OT NULL,    data6   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,    data7   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,    data8   DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,    data9   DECIMAL(20,4) ,    data10  DECIMAL(20,4) ,    data11  DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,    data12  DECIMAL(20,4) NOT NULL,

Comment: you can use [^0-9,],

Comment: [^0-9,], regex is not working if query is in one line

Comment: Okay! ,(?![^(]*\\)) the solution provided by @vks is working fine, you will be able to use this Regex :-)